# Is it ok to use a sender name different from the domain name?

Tags: email

I have an SaaS and my clients send emails through my software to their clients.

Example:

```
My Domain: mysaas.com
My Domains Text: My SaaS Sample
My client name: JW IT Solutions
Email sender: My SaaS Sample - noreply@mysaas.com
Email body: Hello, ..... this email has been sent through My SaaS Sample on behalf of JW IT solutions.
```

It has been working like this for several years, but through all the years, and this month as well, I had clients asking me if it was possible to show **their name** in the `email sender`, like such:

```
Email sender: JW IT Solutions - noreply@mysaas.com
```

I always explained to my clients that this would lead to me impersonating their company, using my software email address, and probably would get me in trouble (SPAM?).

But lately I found myself looking at emails I personally received from other SaaS and I noticed that in some of them, indeed the name of the client appears.

```
Email sender: Lagard IT - invoices@othersaas.com
```

Question: is my concern valid?

Comment: Most SaaS providers like Salesforce, ServiceNow, etc use a form of DMARC to let reciepients that the sender is authorized to send emails on behalf of the customer domain. its a two way street, so they can revoke the authorization from their end (generally by deleting dns records), or you can from yours. the algorithm requires both parties agree and participate in the setup.

Comment: You are talking about the display name not the address right? AFAIK the display name is just that, a display name. It's not taken into account in any protocol or validation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No your concern is not valid.  The display name is largely unimportant.  What matters is the email sender's domain and the configuration of that domain's DNS in conjunction with the outgoing mail server (SPF, DKIM, DMARC, etc.).

Comment: But wouldn't this mean that I can literally send something like "Your Facebook Account - noreply@mysaas.com" and try to hack someone account? If this ain't going to spam..

Comment: If you send spammy emails they will likely be treated as such.  SPF, DKIM, DMARC, etc. are tools to help verify the source of emails and their integrity in transit.  Given that display names are free-form text fields with nothing to authenticate against (e.g. `from: "Dad <bobby@gmail.com>"`) it is the email address domain that is authenticated against.   In answer to your question, It is uncommon to mount hacking attempts from authenticated email addresses.  Normally the reverse is done and the display name looks legit, but the email address is not.

Comment: @user2742861 Yes. The “From:” field is literally like writing a sender’s details on the back of a paper envelope: it’s under the sender’s complete control. Until the advent of DMARC et al., the primary protection against this sort of impersonation was that *replies* would go where the recipient directed them, and hopefully they’d notice if it wasn’t the address of whomever they thought the original sender was!